# JOOQ: how do I add multiple interfaces to generated record classes using matcher strategy

Tags: interface, record, jooq

Building on the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33013153/8707976), I am trying to make my generated records implement multiple interfaces. Depending on which regex matches (REGEX_A, REGEX_B or both), the generated record should implement one, or both of IFoo and IBar.

I do have a *gradle-jooq-plugin* configuration file, but it should be semantically equal to this:

```
<generator>
  <strategy>
    <matchers>
      <tables>
        <table>
          <expression>REGEX_A</expression>
          <recordImplements>com.test.IFoo</recordImplements>
        </table>
        <table>
          <expression>REGEX_B</expression>
          <recordImplements>com.test.IBar</recordImplements>
        </table>
      </tables>
    </matchers>
  </strategy>
</generator>
```

The result I am getting is that a record matching both matchers will only implement IFoo. Is that the expected result? And is there a way to achieve what I want with matcher configuration only?

Answer (score 1):

#### Only the first matching `<table>` specification is applied

The way these matcher strategies work, only the first `<table>` specification whose `<expression>` matches is applied to a generated artifact. The subsequent matches are ignored. This means, you cannot merge the various `<recordImplements/>` specifications. Instead, you'll have to add another specification that matches both your regexes in the beginning, like this:

```xml
<generator>
  <strategy>
    <matchers>
      <tables>
        <table>
          <expression>REGEX_A.*REGEX_B|REGEX_B.*REGEX_A</expression>
          <recordImplements>com.test.IFoo, com.test.IBar</recordImplements>
        </table>
        <table>
          <expression>REGEX_A</expression>
          <recordImplements>com.test.IFoo</recordImplements>
        </table>
        <table>
          <expression>REGEX_B</expression>
          <recordImplements>com.test.IBar</recordImplements>
        </table>
      </tables>
    </matchers>
  </strategy>
</generator>
```

#### Why not merge the various `<table>` specifications?

For `<recordImplements/>`, it seems useful to be able to merge two matching `<table>` matcher specifications and let the resulting records match all the interface implementation specifications.

However, this isn't true for all the other possible elements inside of `<table>`, such as `<tableClass>`, `<tableIdentifier>`, etc., which is why only the *first* matching expression is applied to any table. In order to not complicate this functionality unnecessarily, only the first matching expression is applied.

Comment: The thing is, I had the additional line `<pojoImplements>com.test.IBar</pojoImplements>` in the second matcher, and the POJO _did_ have the interface afterwards. So apparently both matchers matched, but only the first <recordImplements> was used.

Comment: @Sebastian: That shouldn't be the case. Can you perhaps ask a new question with more details about that incident, or create an issue, if you think it's a bug? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose